# inserting a double and a pair in map and printing the map

Tags: c++, dictionary, printing, insert, std-pair

I want to build a container for fractions. The key will represent the value of the fraction in double; The numerator and the denominator are stored in a pair.

`std::map<double, pair<int, int>>  m ();`

I had problems with inserting and printing the elements. Can you tell me how to do it for this specific case?

I tried:

`m.insert(make_pair(x/y, make_pair(x, y)));` 
gives me error

> request for member ‘insert’ in ‘m’, which is of non-class type
> `‘std::map<double, std::pair<int, int> >()’ m.insert(make_pair(x/y, make_pair(x, y)));`

`for ( auto it1 = m.begin(); it1!=m.end(); ++it1) cout << it1->first << "->" << it1->second << endl;` 
gives

> request for member ‘begin’ in ‘m’, which is of non-class type `‘std::map<double, std::pair<int, int> >()’ for ( auto it1 = m.begin(); it1!=m.end(); ++it1)`

and many other ways shown on geeksforgeeks and SO that gave me the same error but i don't know why.

Comment: You're looking for the problem in the wrong place. `std::map<double, pair<int, int>>  m (); ` declares a function `m` that takes no arguments and returns a `std::map<double, pair<int, int>>` - i.e. the function type that the compiler tells you that it has. Remove the `()`. (You can use `{}` instead if you like.)

Answer (score 0):

Your problems lies on what molbdino says:

```cpp
std::map<double, pair<int, int>>  m ();
```

The compiler thinks that it's a function name `m`, has no argument, and returns a `std::map<double, pair<int, int>>` which is not what you want.

So, remove the `()`

Another thing is `x` is an `int`, `y` is an `int`, so `x / y` is an integer division and will return an `int`. But your map wants a `double`.

So you should typecast it into an `double`

Comment: Initially it was `std::map<double, pair<int, int>>` but it gave me segmentation fault in other part ot the program where I'm transforming x from string format to int format using stringstream and a function that I created. I thought that the problem is that the map haven't been initialised, but when i replace `()` with ``{}`` i also get segmentation fault . Maybe the function has some problem, but I've used it many times and there were no problems

Comment: function:
`void tokenize(string const& str,  const char delim, vector<string>& out)
{
    stringstream ss(str);

    string s;

    while (getline(ss, s, delim)) { 
out.push_back(s);
    }
}
`


in main:
`        string container;

        getline(cin, container);

        vector <string> out;

        const char delim = ' ';

        tokenize(container, delim, out);

     std::map<double, pair<int, int>>  m {}; 

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            stringstream geek(out[i]);

            int x = 0, y = 1;
            geek >> x;
          }

Comment: Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringbuf (__mode=24, __str=..., this=0x7ffc91fd7748)
    at /usr/local/include/c++/8.3.0/ext/new_allocator.h:81
81       new_allocator(const new_allocator&) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { }

Comment: @Simona You should ask a new question about the problem that you arise.